# sql query for returning a certain column from a table

Tags: sql

I have two tables which I have to query to get one result, namely the characters that love characters with red hair

Table 1:

```
                   Characters
identification       alias           hair
     22          Luke Skywalker      blond
     23             Han Solo         brown
     24          Leia Skywalker      black
     25              Mara Jade       red
```

Table 2:

```
                         loves
identification  CharacterA_identification   CharacterB_identification
      31                   22                          25
      32                   23                          24
```

Where the second Table indicates which character loves which other character, e.g. Luke Skywalker, with id number 22, loves Mara Jade, with id number 25

I want to write a query that returns all results where CharacterA loves CharacterB if and only if CharacterB has red hair.

This is the query I have but it only gives me back the person with red hair and not the person who likes the person with red hair.-->

```
select C.alias
from   Characters C JOIN Loves L1 JOIN Loves L2
on  C.identification = L1.CharacterA_identification
   AND C.identification = L2.CharacterB_identification 
   AND C.hair = 'red'
```

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm just starting with sql, so I hope this is what you mean with the JOIN syntax

Comment: Note that tables have columns, not "variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       select C.alias 
       from   Characters C 
       where exists (
                     select 1 from loves L INNER JOIN Characters ch                                       
                              on l.CharacterB_identification=ch.identification   
                     where ch. hair = 'red' 
                     and l.CharacterA_identification =c.identification           
                    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But when I run this I get Mara Jade twice, which I was also able to get with my own query. I am trying to get Luke Skywalker as a result which is indeed linked to Mara Jade, but is CharacterA_identification rather than CharacterB_identification. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: which dbms you are using and which version?

Comment: I have revised my answer.